# React Native image takes up all vertical space available

Tags: android, layout, react-native

I am new to react-native (started 2 days ago) but I picked it up quickly because I already knew regular react. I'm trying to write a real world app and I can't figure out how to place an image correctly, I want my Image tag to take up all horizontal space on the screen, but I also want it to stay at the very top of the screen and keep its aspect ratio (which I can't hardcode because I will also display other pictures of licence plates, including european ones that are not 2/1 like in north america), all while not having the actual image take up all available vertical space.

Here is a GIMP edit of what my code renders and what I actually want:
https://ibb.co/XJgrhkC

Here is my render function:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-start', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Image
          source={require(`./resources/images/north_america/original/alaska.jpg`)}
          style={{ flex: 1, width: screenWidth }}
          resizeMode="contain" />
        <Button title="Random state" onPress={this.getRandomState} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I am familiar with css's layout options but react-native seems to be different and I can't wrap my head around all the combinations of widths, flex and resizeModes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use flex, you can see the image automatically occupying a lot of space when you add {borderWidth: 2, borderColor: 'red'}. Instead, you have to specify the height manually. If you want it to be scaled properly, you can try this:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Image, Button, Dimensions } from "react-native";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    imgWidth: 0,
    imgHeight: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Image.getSize("https://i.ibb.co/HgsfWpH/sc128.jpg", (width, height) => {
      // Calculate image width and height
      const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
      const scaleFactor = width / screenWidth;
      const imageHeight = height / scaleFactor;
      this.setState({ imgWidth: screenWidth, imgHeight: imageHeight });
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "center" }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 2
          }}
          source={{
            uri: "https://i.ibb.co/HgsfWpH/sc128.jpg"
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
        <Button title="Random state" onPress={this.getRandomState} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just what I needed. kenmistry's answer was also a step in the right direction, but yours is just a better fit because all my images are not the same aspect ratio and being able to calculate the image's height on the fly is very useful!

Answer (score 1):

typically, upon applying `flex` to the `<View />` tag enclosing the `<Image />` and the `<Button />`, the children of the parent component will have the same `flex` prop applied. so, you can remove the `flex` prop under `<Image />`.

having dealt with `<Image />` in react-native for some time, i must say that specifying values for both `height` and `width` is important for an `<Image />` to be displayed properly.

you can try it out on my Expo example [here](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/flex-test).

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center'
      }}>
        <Image
          source={require(`./resources/images/north_america/original/alaska.jpg`)}
          style={{
            width: screenWidth,
            height: 200,
          }}
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
        <Button
          title="Random state"
          onPress={this.getRandomState}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

also, since you are new to react-native, may i suggest you change `<Button />` to `<TouchableOpacity />`? it provides a visual aid when user presses it on a mobile device.